# Why am I getting a Segmentation fault for local array?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a program which stores data in a local array and can call either mergesort or bubblesort to the sort the contents of that array in ascending order. The program works fine for an input of 10 items or so, but I immediately receive a seg fault when I try to run the program  on a very large data set. If I use a dynamic array, there's no issue but, for this project, I have to use a local array. I've tried setting 'ulimit -s' to values significantly higher than the required memory space, but I still get a seg fault. How can I avoid a segmentation fault while still using a local array. I've attached my code.

The seg fault occurs in this part of the code, with the array declaration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int MaxSize = 2100000;

int main(){

    ifstream infile; //use provided class to create stream object for reading
    ofstream outfile; //use provided class to create stream object for writing
    //long int *p = new long [MaxSize];

    long int array[MaxSize]; //declare array
    double begin_time, end_time, cpu_time_used;

    infile.open("lab5_input.txt");
    if (infile.is_open()) //checks if file is really open
    {
        cout << "File successfully opened" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file";
    }

    int option;

} //declare variable
```

Comment: What value is MaxSize? And why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: MaxSize is 2100000. I was having issues with the formatting on this site, so I only posted the part where the seg fault seems to be occurring, but I have "using namespace std" elsewhere in my program.

Comment: Don't put very large things on the stack or you might cause a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768789/why-am-i-getting-a-segmentation-fault-for-local-array)!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your array size. You can't have an array the size of 2100000. Try making the array smaller. I tried this on GCC and MSVC and both programs crashed, until I decreased the array size. Like @MatsPetersson said, a better alternative to arrays are vectors for C++, unless you can't use STL.

Comment: Array size is def the issue. My program has worked for smaller input files. Unfortunately, for this project, I have to process an array of that large size for this particular assignment

Comment: @FredToews you can use different flavours of array which don't cause stack overflow. `static long int array[MaxSize];` would be one. Another would be `std::vector<long int> array(MaxSize);` .